# How to highlight duplicates faster in google sheets script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wrote function `markDupes1Col` which highlights all duplicates in column. It works great, but when number of rows has passed 50k it became really slow. Is there anything I can do to make it faster?

```
function removeEmptyCells(values) {
  values = values.filter(function (el) {
    return el != null && el[0] !== '' && el[0] != null;
  });
  return values;
}

function findDupes(arr) {
  var sortedData = arr.slice().sort();
  var duplicates = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < sortedData.length; i++) {
    if (sortedData[i] && sortedData[i] !== '' && sortedData[i + 1] == sortedData[i]) {
      duplicates.push(sortedData[i]);
    }
  }
  return duplicates;
}

function markDupes1Col() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(appId);
  var sheetName = arguments[0];
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  for(var n = 1; n < arguments.length; n++) {
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    if (lastRow == 0) lastRow = 1;
    var rangeArray = sheet.getRange(1, arguments[n], lastRow);

    var valuesArray = rangeArray.getValues();
    valuesArray = removeEmptyCells(valuesArray);

    // Convert to one dimensional array
    valuesArray = [].concat.apply([], valuesArray);

    var duplicates = findDupes(valuesArray);

    rangeArray.setBackground(null);

    if (duplicates.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < valuesArray.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < duplicates.length; j++) {
          if (valuesArray[i] == duplicates[j]) {
            sheet.getRange(i + 1, arguments[n]).setBackground("#b7e1cd");
            break;
          }
        } 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't do this with conditional formatting? Custom formula is, `=COUNTIF(A:A,A:A)>1`

Comment: Because it is even slower than my script.

Comment: Try, if possible, to [remove](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/rowcolumn) empty rows or columns, or divide the Spreadsheet into several Spreadsheet files. I don't think the code itself can be more optimised.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, all empty rows and columns were already removed. Dividing the spreadsheet is impossible. I guess there should be a trick to avoid double for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Issue(Slow performance):

- Use of `setBackground` in a loop for each cell.
- Use of arrays to store duplicates.

#### Solution:

- Create a output array and use `setBackgrounds()` instead.
- Use Objects `{}` to store duplicates
- If the above solutions are still slow, use sheets api to batch set backgrounds

#### Snippet:

```
function findDupes(arr){
  var valObj = {};
  var duplicates = {};
  arr.forEach(function(row){
    var el = row[0];
    if(el in valObj){ 
      duplicates[el] = 1 
    } else {
      valObj[el] = 1;
    }
  })
  return duplicates;
}

//....

valuesArray = removeEmptyCells(valuesArray);
//valuesArray = [].concat.apply([], valuesArray); Removed
var duplicates = findDupes(valuesArray);

//.....
rangeArray.setBackgrounds(
  valuesArray.map(function(row){
    return [(row[0] in duplicates) ? "#b7e1cd" : null]
  })
)
```

#### References:

- [Best practices § Use Batch Operations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations)
- [Range § setBackgrounds](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundscolor)

Comment: Thank you. I also removed `valuesArray = removeEmptyCells(valuesArray);` and replaced `return...` with `return [((row[0] in duplicates) && (row[0] !== '')) ? "#b7e1cd" : null]`. But one remark: if the last row is colored duplicate, and then remove it... its cell stays colored.

Comment: @dereks  Great. Your remark is unclear. My snippet doesn't do anything specific with the lastrow.  You might want to ask that as a new question.

Comment: You're right. I suppose if you delete value in the last cell (already colored) `valuesArray` is not getting this element (because the cell is empty). That is why map function does not work on it. And this cell stays colored.

Comment: @dereks I guess if you want to restore defaults first, something like this should work `sheet.getRange('1:'+sheet.getMaxRows()).setBackground('white')`